# Ordering columns in data frame

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame with the following column names:

```
well, DIV10SD7, DIV11SD7, DIV7SD7, DIV9SD7
```

However, I want the order to be the following:

```
well, DIV7SD7, DIV9SD7, DIV10SD7, DIV11SD7
```

So basically, I want to sort by the number after "DIV" and before "SD7". Additionally, I want to leave out the "well" column when I sort.

When I use the following command:

```
df[,order(names(df))]
```

The order of the data frame is unchanged, with the exception of the well column, which moves to the end. I believe this is because R reads each string one character at a time. So, in this case, all the numbers that begin with 1 (e.g. DIV10 and DIV11) are placed before DIV7 and DIV9.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the `mixedorder` function from the "gtools" package:

```
mydf[c(1, mixedorder(names(mydf)[-1]) + 1)]
##   well DIV7SD7 DIV9SD7 DIV10SD7 DIV11SD7
## 1    1       7       9        3        5
## 2    2       8      10        4        6
```

Sample data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(well = 1:2, DIV10SD7 = 3:4, DIV11SD7 = 5:6, DIV7SD7 = 7:8, 
        DIV9SD7 = 9:10), .Names = c("well", "DIV10SD7", "DIV11SD7", 
    "DIV7SD7", "DIV9SD7"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

---

I'd also suggest converting your dataset to a `data.table` so that you can make use of the `set` functions in "data.table" (like `setcolorder`). This will let you update the column order by reference.